# Hide Feign client endpoints in Swagger

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, netflix-feign

I am using Springboot autoconfiguration, and currently all my Feign endpoints are exposed in swagger-ui. How can I disable this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far the best way to not include unrelated endpoints is through Swagger `Docker`, e.g.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
class SwaggerConf {
  @Bean
  Docket allApis() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
      .groupName("all")
      .select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.example.base"))
      .build();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set this in your `application.properties` as:

```
endpoints.enabled=false
endpoints.health.enabled=true
endpoints.loggers.enabled=true
```

In your case it will be something like

```
endpoints.feign.***=true
```

But this is not disabling for swagger but endpoints exposure themselves. For Swagger you have to markup them explicitly with `@Api#hidden()` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution that worked for me is to add **@ApiIgnore** to the Feign Client

```
@ApiIgnore    
@FeignClient()
public interface FeignApi {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be old now, but for future Googlerer's here's what was the easy fix for me :

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(RestController.class))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Instead of using Predicates and package, better to ask swagger to scan only classes annotated with RestController / Controller. Because FiegnClient interfact isn't a Controller / RestController, it won't be scanned by Swagger !

Hope that helps.